# MySQL and PHP performance of multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

I'm asking you for some advice. I have a website where I have videos and users can give them thumbs up and thumbs down. Their saved in a single table. Currently I have three sql queries to get the count of thumbs up, the count of thumbs down and what the logged in user gave (if he did).

And now I'm thinking about making that more performance, but I don't know what is better, since I want to keep the count of queries down.

Method 1) Keep these three queries as they are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND `thumb` = '1' LIMIT 1
SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND `thumb` = '0' LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND `uid` = '1' LIMIT 1
```

Method 2) Make one query with sub queries (something like that (it doesn't work how it is here)):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND `thumb` = '1' LIMIT 1) as thumbsups, (SELECT COUNT(*) as rowcount FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND `thumb` = '0' LIMIT 1) as thumbsdowns FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx' AND (`uid` = '1' OR `uid` = NULL)
```

Method 3) Your own idea, maybe?

Tell me what you think and give some code (if you want).

Best Regards
Charlotte

edit: I'll add some more information:
vid is the id of the video. Everything about the likes is stored in this table, referenced to the video with the VideoID (vid). uid is the UserID who gave the like (or dislike). That means there isn't only the likes and dislikes of one video in this table. To know which like and dislike is for which video, the like will be stored with the videoid.

Comment: Perhaps use a UNION so that it can all be run at one time. You could also create a stored procedure that gets called once and returns all of the data.

Comment: I'd recommend to keep the historical `videolikes` table, and store that information, but to also store the counts with the video record.

Comment: +1 to what @Sonny said. If you are concerned about performance, simply keep a counter col in your video table. Then in your function that inserts video likes, increment the counter in the video table.

Comment: Hmm, it's amazing: I found numerous answers to this question after searching :<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could use a single query for the up/down votes:

```
SELECT SUM(thumb = 1) AS upvote, SUM(thumb = 0) AS downvote, ....
```

MySQL will take the boolean true/false results of those `thumb = X` tests, convert to integer `0` or `1`, and then sum them up

Comment: That wouldn't work and will only result in 1 upvote or 1 downvote since the WHERE clausel includes the userid and videoid and only one row will be returned and that's his vote. I can be wrong, but that would mean you'd have to construct the full query so I can understand what you want to do.

Comment: yes, you'd have to run your `uid` query separately. the above query would be run on the entire table with a simple `where vid=XXX` filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the first two queries like that:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(`thumb` = 1, 1, 0)) AS rowcountthumb0,
  SUM(IF(`thumb` = 0, 1, 0)) AS rowcountthumb1
FROM `videolikes` WHERE `vid` = 'gt6w_RZfs5yx'
```

Since the last query seems to be semantically different, I would keep it separate from the one mentioned here for clarity.